# Wordpress Sharing Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know what sharing plugin this is...

wensite 1: www.vigilantcitizen.com

website 2: www.tooxclusive.com

[Sharer Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mntee.jpg)

[Sharer Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk1JJ.jpg)

Comment: Can you include the website where you find this share buttons?

Comment: Link to screenshot as been added

Comment: We need the website not a screenshot

Comment: I just added website! @cgee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website (www.tooxclusive.com) use this plugin:

http://getsocial.io/wordpress-share